# Making a code to disable a css of a tag and enable the css on an other tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website and I want to make a guide with pulse animation. There are 3 tags that I want to use. For example three `<a>` links, I want:

- first link starts pulsing and when I clicked on it its css be disabled and
- the second link starts pulsing, and
- a third one like this

I think it may be possible with javascript but I dont know how.

For example:

```css
   #live-heart{
    animation:pulse 1500ms infinite ;
    border-radius:20px;
   }
   @keyframes pulse{
     0% {
       box-shadow:#f33 0 0 0 0;
     }
     75%{
       box-shadow:rgba(65, 30, 30, 0.8) 0 0 0 16px
     }
   }
      #live-heart2{
    animation:pulse 1500ms infinite ;
    border-radius:20px;
   }
   @keyframes pulse{
     0% {
       box-shadow:#f33 0 0 0 0;
     }
     75%{
       box-shadow:rgba(65, 30, 30, 0.8) 0 0 0 16px
     }
   }
      #live-heart3{
    animation:pulse 1500ms infinite ;
    border-radius:20px;
   }
   @keyframes pulse{
     0% {
       box-shadow:#f33 0 0 0 0;
     }
     75%{
       box-shadow:rgba(65, 30, 30, 0.8) 0 0 0 16px
     }
   }
```

```html
<a href="#" id="live-heart2">first one</a>
<p>
When a user clicked on "first one" its css shoul be disabled and a second one that I linked in paragraph be enabled <a href="#" id="live-heart">second one</a>
and when a user clicked on second one, its css be disabled and the third one be activeted
example text: bla bla bla bla
</p>
<a href="#" id="live-heart3">third one</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

basically all you need is to having a state holding the active pulsing link index. and by clicking it, increase the index by one.

something like that:

```js
const [isPulsingIndex, setIsPulsingIndex] = useState(0);

<Link className={isPulsing.index === 0 ? 'pulsing' : ''} 
  onClick={() => setIsPulsingIndex(1)}>
    Link 1
</Link>
<Link className={isPulsing.index === 1 ? 'pulsing' : ''} 
  onClick={() => setIsPulsingIndex(2)}>
    Link 1
</Link>
<Link className={isPulsing.index === 2 ? 'pulsing' : ''} 
  onClick={() => setIsPulsingIndex(3)}>
    Link 1
</Link>
```

quick example of how adding and removing class from a tag dynamically using state

Comment: may you set it in my code please? i cant understand what i should do with the code you write exactly

Comment: are you using react? or vanilla js? if react, add a state as a showed you above (read about react hooks useState) and add the onClick and className props to the <p> tags

Comment: no im making a simple website page with html css

Comment: So instead of the state, add a global variable holding the index of the current pulsing link, and when clicking on the p element, it increases the global variable by one.